# Assembly 8086 how can I convert a db to a decimal number?

Tags: string, assembly, hex, decimal, x86-16

I'm trying to make a convertor from hexadecimal to decimal and the program works fine.
the thing is it stores the decimal value as string divided to digits so it would be much easier to print it, Lets say the input is FFFF the decimal value will be stored in a db as 6,5,5,3,5,$ (max 6 slots), how can I store these values into 1 dw so it would be 65535?
I'm pretty new to assembly thought so it would be helpful if you would show me some code examples too.

the code to convert hexadecimal to numbers

```
HEX2NUMBER PROC
      MOV AX, 0      
   CICLO:
      SHL  AL, 1
      RCL  AH, 1
      SHL  AL, 1
      RCL  AH, 1
      SHL  AL, 1
      RCL  AH, 1
      SHL  AL, 1
      RCL  AH, 1

      MOV  BL, [ SI ]  

      call validate

      CMP  BL, 'A'   
      JAE  LETTER_AF    
   ;CharIsDigit09.
      SUB  BL, 48     
      JMP  CONTINUE   
   LETTER_AF:               
      SUB  BL, 55     
   CONTINUE: 
      OR   AL, BL     
      INC  SI         
      DEC  BH         
      JNZ  CICLO       
   FIN:
      RET
HEX2NUMBER endp
```

The code to convert the number to string

```
NUMBER2STRING PROC
  MOV BX, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  MOV CX, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
CYCLE1:       
  MOV DX, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  DIV BX ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  PUSH DX ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  INC CX ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  CMP AX, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  JNE CYCLE1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
  LEA SI, buffer
CYCLE2:  
  POP DX        
  ADD DL, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  MOV [SI], DL
  INC SI
  LOOP CYCLE2 
  
  ;CALL STORE_TO_DW 

  RET
NUMBER2STRING ENDP
```

Convert from string to number

```
STRING2NUMBER PROC
  MOV BX, 10 
  MOV CX, 0 
CYCLE1_NUM:       
  MOV DX, 0 
  MUL BX 
  PUSH DX 
  INC CX 
  CMP AX, 0  
  JNE CYCLE1_NUM 
  LEA SI, NUM
CYCLE2_NUM:  
  POP DX        
  MOV [SI], DL
  INC SI
  LOOP CYCLE2_NUM                   
                  
              RET    
STRING2NUMBER ENDP
```

Comment: You already have a NUMBER2STRING procedure. STRING2NUMBER is the opposite; i.e. repeated multiplication by 10 and accumulation.

Comment: I tried that, posted the code above /\ It does not working, what did I do wrong?

Comment: That's not the opposite. The procedure isn't supposed to write to memory. It should multiply the running total by 10, read a character from the string, convert the character into the corresponding number and add it to the running total. Repeat until all characters have been read.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, can you please show me a code for example?

Comment: If you want your code be robust and accept signum `-` or `+`, look at my macro [LodD](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/cpuext16.htm#LodD).